# Get original image dimensions when embedding image in WordprocessingML

Tags: xml, ms-word, wordml

I am dynamically creating Word documents using the Velocity template engine. The documents are created in XML (using the Microsoft Office 2003 WordprocessML XML standard).

I am embedding an image (encoded in Base64 format) inside the WordML in the traditional way:

```
<w:pict>  
    <v:shapeType> ... </v:shapeType>    
    <w:binData w:name="wordml://02000002.jpg"> [ encoded data] </w:binData>

    <v:shape id="_x0000_s1026"  
           type="#_x0000_t75"
           style="width:100%;height:100%" 
           o:allowoverlap="f"
           >
        <v:imagedata src="wordml://02000002.jpg" o:title="testimage2">
        </v:imagedata>
    </v:shape>

</w:pict>
```

The issue is with image sizing / scaling. Note the `style` attribute on the `<v:shape>` tag. Setting height and width to 100% **does not** size the image to its actual size. It sets height and width to approximately 1.04 inches which skews the image. Leaving off the height and width has the same effect. Setting height and width to `auto` has the same effect.

Most annoyingly, if I open the generated document in Word 2003, right click on the image, open the Format Picture dialog, and go to the Size tab it display the correct height and width under "Original size." It even provides a "Reset" button that resizes the image to its original size (assuming the "Relative to original picture size" checkbox is checked.)

I am like: !*@&#^#% ???

**So my question is:**

*Is there anyway in the context of WordML to get the original size values for the image (or instruct Word to **use** the original image size)?*

If someone can help will this question, I promise I will write an in depth blog post to ensure that I will be the *last* person that has to deal with this.

Comment: Maybe the framework that you are using to generate the XML document provides a method to retrieve the size of the image? Or it can be extended so that it does?

Comment: I could do the image processing in my Java code and pass the height/width through to the velocity context. That is possible but not ideal in my situation. (I currently have a prototype that does that, but because of differences in image resolution (75 dpi versus 96) it does not always work well.)

Comment: I am dealing with this as we speak. Did you by any chance find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xslt templates you can write some C# script in your template like that(it's for metafiles(.wmf) but you can rewrite it for Bitmap class to use with .jpg format):

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
     <msxsl:assembly name="System.Drawing" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Drawing.Imaging" />


     <![CDATA[

          public static double getImageWidthFrom64String(string base64)
            {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile image;
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                image =
(System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile)System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile.FromStream(ms);
            }
       return image.Width;
            }

             public static double getImageHeightFrom64String(string base64)
            {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile image;
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                image =
(System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile)System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile.FromStream(ms);
            }      
            return image.Height;
            }
     ]]>
      </msxsl:script>
```

Then you can use these functions to get real image size in your template:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns1:Work/ns1:leaderSignature">
    <ns1:picture>
      <xsl:for-each select="@ns1:*|@*[namespace-uri()='']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat(concat('leadsig',ancestor::ns1:Work/ns1:id),'.wmz')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="file64String" select="."></xsl:variable> 
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:pict>    
          <w:binData w:name="{concat('wordml:\\',$filename)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </w:binData>
          <v:shape id="pic3" o:spid="_x0000_s1028"  style="
            width:{user:getImageWidthFrom64String($file64String)};
            height:{user:getImageHeightFrom64String($file64String)};
            position:absolute;         
            text-align:left;
            left:0;
            margin-left:430pt;
            margin-top:192pt;       
            z-index:2;   
            visibility:visible;
            mso-position-horizontal-relative:page;
            mso-position-horizontal:absolute;
            mso-position-vertical-relative:page;
            mso-position-vertical:absolute;   
            mso-wrap-style:square;
            mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;
            mso-wrap-distance-top:0;
            mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;
            mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0">         
            <v:imagedata src="{concat('wordml:\\',$filename)}" o:title="" />
           <w10:wrap anchorx="page" anchory="page" />
          </v:shape>
        </w:pict>  
      </w:r>
    </ns1:picture>
  </xsl:template><!--Leader Signature-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width and height in "style" attribute of "v:shape" element to 0px. For example:

```
<v:shape style="width:0px;height:0px" >
```

And image will have original size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you relying on WordML to get the image size? You are feeding an image into word document, you can get image size by using Bitmap class.